# Python Telegram создать данные callback_data без нажатия inline кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, callback

При создании инлайновых кнопок у кнопки есть параметр - callback_data
Каким образом можно его создать "искусственно"?

Грубо говоря, сымитировать нажатие кнопки пользователем.

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий вопрос", callback_data = "ticket_21.1")
button_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Почему?", callback_data = "20.20.r")
keyboard.add(button_1, button_2)
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Верный ответ!', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: для каких целей это нужно - если сымитировать клик кнопки, то просто передайте строку как текст из `callback_data`, а вообще это тип данных `aiogram`, можете свой экземпляр `callback` создать

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
...

    class XClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.message = call.message
            self.data = 'review'

    callback_inline(XClass())
```

в итоге получиться имитация нажатия кнопки у которой `callback_data=review`